# Two kind of authetication in cake PHP- by different cross field

Tags: php, cakephp

In my application I need to check the user authentication by two way first across username and **password**(both are database field),
cake php already give this by

```
  $this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'username', 
        'password' => 'password'
        );
```

NOw MY need is if in first case user can not authenticate then check the user data across username and **forgot_password**(both are database field) 
for that how can I use Auth component fields?  I have tried :

```
else
{
$this->Auth->fields = array(
        'username' => 'username', 
        'password' => 'forgot_password'
        );
$this->Auth->login();       
}
```

But this didn't work..is there any other way?
I need both type of cross check condition as if else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to use `$this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();`.

```
<?php
function login()
{       
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        if (!$this->Auth->login())
        {
            $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'username',
                                                'password' => 'forgot_password')));
            $this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();
            if ($this->Auth->login())
            {
                //Your message here
                //redirect to further pages
            }
            else
            {
                //redirect to login page
            }
        }
    }
}
```